# How to add a dropdown list within a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I've looked at multiple questions and their answers on this site concerning this but none of those navi drawers seem to be like how I've done mine.

```
public class Main extends Activity  {

    // Navigation Drawer variables
    private String[] navMenu = new String[] { "Home", "Menu", "Settings" };
    private DrawerLayout navDrawer;
    private ListView navList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> navAdapter;

    // Fragments
    private Home fHome = new Home();
    private Menu fMenu = new Menu();
    private Settings fSettings = new Settings();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navigationDrawer();// Navigation Drawer setup


    }

    private void navigationDrawer() {
        navDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        navAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, navMenu);
        navList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1c2d4b"));
        navList.setAdapter(navAdapter);
        navList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                navDrawer.closeDrawers();
                //TODO Switch current fragment
                //navMenu[position]
            }

        });
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Above is my Main and it's xml layout, how would I make the `Menu` item in `navMenu` a drop down list? I'm fairly new to using Navigation Drawers so although it runs fine, I'm not sure if I've even done it the proper way.

Comment: You might want to look at [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). It's a fantastic library for doing Material Design drawer layouts.

Comment: @cwbowron I'd rather avoid using libraries outside of the standard Android ones.